# Webpack, How to find unused file in project?

Tags: webpack

example:

there are many image files in `images/` directory.

search and delete the unused files manually are inefficiency.

I use `webpack1.x`

here is my case:

`var req = require.context('./images', true, /\.(jpg|png)$/);`

`req.keys().forEach(file => req(file));`

I want to `require` the files which is used, not all files.

So, I think I must remove the files unused.

Is there any way to solve my case?